# form field with error not resetting even after form set to pristine : AngularJs

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation

in my HTML :

```
<form class="form_page login-frm" name="loginForm" novalidate>
   <input type="email" ng-model="data.username" name='username' required autofocus>
   <div class="info-message">
     <small ng-show='(loginForm.username.$error.required || loginForm.username.$error.email) && loginForm.username.$dirty'>The acceptable format for the username includes an '@'.
     </small>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.cancel = function() {
  $scope.loginForm.$setPristine();
  angular.element(this)[0].loginForm.$setPristine();
  delete $scope.data.username;
};
```

But after this also, if the username is incorrect and error message is showing and the cancel button is clicked then the error message gets erased but the username field never empties.How to empty the username also.And also after deleting the value why is it visible?

Comment: $scope.data.username = '' ?

Comment: isnt deleting the value a better approach. You see i have other fields too and deleting those workss for me if there is no error on those

Comment: No. The model is centre to an angular app and if you start carving chunks out of it then you will suffer. Add a function called reset to the data object and set all the values to null or empty string or 0.

Comment: EUREKA :  if the form field is errorenous then the ng-model does not update.

Answer (score 1):

Set `$scope.data.username` to the empty string or to undefined, instead of deleting it. You also do not need the line with `angular.element(...)` in your controller.

Comment: isnt deleting the value a better approach. You see i have other fields too and deleting those workss for me if there is no error on those

Comment: Deleting means the property doesn't exist, which means JavaScript will search up the prototypal chain. In the case of a form, this is rarely what you want. Setting it to an empty or undefined value is, in my opinion, cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I created plunkr to answer your question. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/1XblX3?p=preview
In more object oriented way you should do this.

```
var User = function(username) {
    this.username = username;
};
User.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.username = "";
};
$scope.user = new User("Ali");
$scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.message = "Resetting form";
    $scope.userForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.user.reset();
};
```